# Textbox problem with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have used a regex function on a textbox, but it's not working.

```
<input name="title" class="txtbxinput" id="title"
onblur="showsongstatus(this.value);title(this);" 
onkeyup="title(this);" size="58" >

function title(f) {
   f.value = f.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s.'-]/gixsm,'');
   f.value = f.value.replace(/\s\s+/g, '\s'); //remove more than 2 white spaces.
   f.value = f.value.replace(/'{2,}/g, '\'');
   f.value = f.value.replace(/--/g, '-');
   f.value = f.value.replace(/\.\./g, '\.');
return f;
}
```

I have restricted it for alphabets, hyphen, dots, and single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a function named `title` that happens to have the same name as your `id`.

To fix, just change your function name. For example, the following works:

```
<input name="title" class="txtbxinput" id="title"
onblur="showsongstatus(this.value); doTitle(this);" 
onkeyup="doTitle(this);" size="58" >

function doTitle(f) {
   f.value = f.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s.'-]/gixsm,'');
   f.value = f.value.replace(/\s\s+/g, '\s'); //remove more than 2 white spaces.
   f.value = f.value.replace(/'{2,}/g, '\'');
   f.value = f.value.replace(/--/g, '-');
   f.value = f.value.replace(/\.\./g, '\.');
return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write javascript code like:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeypress="return check(event);" />

function check(evt) {
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode            
            if ((charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) || (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) || charCode == 39 || charCode == 46 || charCode == 45)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
```